# Can I use Visual Studio Code Coverage for existing tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have Visual Studio 2010 also existing tests which are not Visual Studio unit tests . Can I use the code coverage tools by Visual Studio , I am under the impression it can be done only if the tests are created by Visual Studio .

Comment: What do you mean by `created by Visual Studio`. Started from VS? Or MSTest unit tests? If started then answer is yes you don't need VS to use code coverage, you may launch code coverage from command line. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299398%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I mean unit test created using visual studio , I have already got some test framework I wanted to check code coverage with those